# I would like to extract every first head from the file `locale.gen` via `locale-gen`

Tags: bash, docker

I am using the Docker image and am building a dockerfile. The file `locale.gen` (from `/etc/locale.gen`) contains the comments with `#` alongside the languages:

```yaml
ca_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Catalan (Spain)
de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8 # German (Germany)
el_GR.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Greek (Greece)
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8 # English (United Kingdom)
en_NZ.UTF-8 UTF-8 # English (New Zealand)
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 # English (United States)
eo          UTF-8 # Esperanto
es_AR.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Spanish (Argentina)
es_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Spanish (Spanish)
es_UY.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Spanish (Uruguay)
eu_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Basque (Spain)
fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8 # French (France)
it_IT.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Italian (Italy)
ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Japanese (Japan)
ka_GE.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Georgian (Georgia)
ko_KR.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Korean (Korea)
mi_NZ.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Maori (New Zealand)
nl_NL.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Dutch (Netherlands)
pt_BR.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Portuguese (Brazil)
pt_PT.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Portuguese (Portugal)
ro_RO.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Romanian (Romania)
ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Russian (Russia)
uk_UA.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Ukranian (Ukraine)
xh_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Xhosa (South Africa)
zh_CN.UTF-8 UTF-8 # Chinese (China)
```

If I run the simple command `locale-gen`, it'll fail because of the comments, it is why I have to use the option `awk -F "#" '{print $1}'`, but it still failed.

See how it looks like in the dockerfile:

```
#  Setting the system keyboard and language
#  A definir o idioma e o teclado do sistema
COPY ./config/languages/locale-minimal.gen /etc/locale.gen
RUN locale-gen | awk -F "#" '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Which docker image are you using?

Comment: Arch Linux. Check https://hub.docker.com/r/archlinux/archlinux. Of course I install `glibc` before generating the new languages.

Comment: @roaima, observe that `./config/languages/local-minimal.gen` is outside the Docker image, the Docker image does not find it. It needs to copied inside before. The user interested in the Docker image will check that file without comments and ask what language is.

Comment: I also intend to copy my locale-gen with comments to `/etc/locale.gen` when I also make a clean installation. I want to see still the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you consider changing your Docker file to copy the source file across and then modify it:

```
#  Setting the system keyboard and language
#  A definir o idioma e o teclado do sistema
COPY ./config/languages/locale-minimal.gen /etc/locale.gen.orig
RUN sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*#.*//' -e '/^$/d' /etc/locale.gen.orig >/etc/locale.gen
RUN locale-gen
```

If you don't want to keep an original copy in your Docker instance you could copy it across and edit it *in situ*:

```
COPY ./config/languages/locale-minimal.gen /etc/locale.gen
RUN sed -i -e 's/[[:space:]]*#.*//' -e '/^$/d' /etc/locale.gen
RUN locale-gen
```

Comment: Docker's `/etc/locale.gen` is full. Does this `sed` empty or remove the whole Docker's original `/etc/locale.gen` before copy the languages to the new empty `locale.gen`?

Comment: The first example.

Comment: It copies your template file to `/etc/locale.gen.orig` and then processes that to generate `/etc/locale.gen`, replacing whatever contents it had. Since your original `COPY` did that too I didn't see a problem mimicking it